# Removing Duplicates in String -Python

Tags: python-2.7

I found this code online, but not sure how it is working. I am not able to understand what below line does,

```
if ans_str.find(s) == -1:
        ans_str += s
```

the complete code:

```
def remove_dup(string): 
   ans_str = string[0]

   for s in string:
      if ans_str.find(s) == -1:
          ans_str += s

   return ans_str

print remove_dup("aabbacc")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_dup(string): 
   ans_str = string[0] # sets "ans_str" equal to the first character of string

   for s in string: # loops through all of the characters in string
      if ans_str.find(s) == -1: 
          # this checks if the current letter can be found in ans_strin
          # if the current letter is found it will return 0 if not it returns -1
          ans_str += s # this appends the current character to ans_str if ans_string.find() returns -1
   return ans_str 

print remove_dup("aabbacc")
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is basically creating a new string from the input `string` while removing the duplicate characters.

`ans_string` initially starts with just the first character, which in this case is `a`.

Let's look at the main part of the function:

```
for s in string:
  if ans_str.find(s) == -1:
      ans_str += s
```

What this does is, for every character in `string` we look for that character in `ans_str`. This is done by using `ans_str.find(s)`. If the character is already present in the string, it will return the index at which it is present else it will return -1. Hence, if it returns -1, it means the character assigned to `s` does not exist in `ans_str` and we can safely add it to `ans_str`, else we ignore that character.

The function should return `abc` on input `aabbacc`.